# Understanding the returned solution in Algorithm X

Tags: list, algorithm, sudoku

As a CS student I want to do some project for myself that interests me.
I decided to make a Sudoku game in Java. While reading material on the internet on how to solve a Sudoku game efficiently, I stumbled upon an algorithm by Donald Knuth which called Algorithm-X.
I read his PDF that can be found here: [https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Ejchu/publicportal/sudoku/0011047.pdf)
in order to implement his algorithm by myself, but I don't quite understand the returned solution.
As can be seen in the PDF, on page 2 there's a matrix that he represents as a Dancing List on page 6.
On the bottom of page 5, he explains the solution we will return if the algorithm finds a good solution.
The returned solution is the name of the columns, and the concrete solution can be seen on page 8.

The solution should be a representation of the rows we want to take in order to cover all elements in the universe. For the given matrix, the first, fourth and fifth rows are enough here.
I don't really see how this fits with the solution that the algorithm built and returned on page 8.

If someone maybe can elaborate on this I would be more than happy to understand how this works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? How the answer on page 8 corresponds to rows 1, 4 and 5? The solution is printed in terms of the elements ("1" columns) in the rows 4 (AD), 5 (BG) and 1 (CEF). Or how the solution is returned? The solution isn't returned; each solution is printed as it is found on the deepest recursion level. To do that, a reference object (O in the paper) for each level is kept.

Comment: The first one was what I didn't understand, but after you've explained it now I can see the whole picture.
Thanks for the fast reply and the clear explanation!